# How to find and match all common terms in two matrices (different sized rows) and replace the common terms with matching row on second matrix

Tags: r

I have two matrices, and I want to replace the "target_id" column in matrix 1 with the "external_gene_name" in matrix 2 which is in the same row as the "target_id".

E.x.

Matrix 1:

```
                      KO_1D_7dpi  KO_2D_7dpi  KO_3D_7dpi    KO_4D_7dpi WT_1D_7dpi
ENSMUST00000221393.2 -13.8155106   0.5522234   0.2745596   0.260108646 -13.815511
ENSMUST00000059802.7 -13.8155106 -13.8155106 -13.8155106 -13.815510558   5.466629
ENSMUST00000185334.7   0.6350789   0.1733741   0.1357635   0.437655396 -13.815511
```

Matrix 2:

```
               external_gene_name
ENSMUST00000221393.2                 gene1
ENSMUST00000059802.7                 gene2
ENSMUST00000185334.7                 gene3
```

Desired Matrix:

```
      KO_1D_7dpi  KO_2D_7dpi  KO_3D_7dpi    KO_4D_7dpi WT_1D_7dpi
gene1 -13.8155106   0.5522234   0.2745596   0.260108646 -13.815511
gene2 -13.8155106 -13.8155106 -13.8155106 -13.815510558   5.466629
gene3 0.6350789   0.1733741   0.1357635   0.437655396 -13.815511
```

I tried using `left_join` and `lapply` functions but they didn't work. Would appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Consider adding dput(matrix1) structure(...) and dput(matrix2) structure(...), as data above. But it look like you're looking for `table`.

Comment: I don’t see `target_id` in `matrix1` - I suggest following Chris’s advice and adding the code to recreate the exact structure.

Comment: `rownames(matrix_1) <- matrix_2[match(rownames(matrix_1), rownames(matrix_2)),1]`

Answer (score 2):

```
idx <- match(rownames(matrix_1), rownames(matrix_2))

rownames(matrix_1)[idx] <- matrix_2[idx,"external_gene_name"]

      KO_1D_7dpi  KO_2D_7dpi  KO_3D_7dpi  KO_4D_7dpi WT_1D_7dpi
gene1 -13.8155106   0.5522234   0.2745596   0.2601086 -13.815511
gene2 -13.8155106 -13.8155106 -13.8155106 -13.8155106   5.466629
gene3   0.6350789   0.1733741   0.1357635   0.4376554 -13.815511
```

Comment: I recived this error when I tried your second line of code:Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Comment: @Ivan what is `dn`, why are you trying to replace all the `dimnames(x)`? Your code and my code are different

Comment: I'm not sure what ```dn``` is, but this is the exact code that I ran: ```idx <- match(rownames(count), rownames(gene_names))

rownames(count)[idx] <- gene_names[idx,"external_gene_name"]```